# Tomcat is logging everything to stdout

Tags: tomcat, java, logging, tomcat6, servlet

I have Tomcat 6 installed as a Windows service. All log messages from my web application **dreambear** (logged with `getServletContext().log()`) are going to the stdout log instead of the log file I specified. This happened even before I added the dreambear logger, when the messages should still have gotten to the localhost log instead stdout.

Below are the contents of *logging.properties*. The specified log files are created, though empty, so there probably isn't a syntax error or something like that in this file.

```
handlers = \
    1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, \
    2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, \
    3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, \
    4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, \
    5dreambear.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, \
    java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost.

3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = manager.

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = host-manager.

5dreambear.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
5dreambear.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
5dreambear.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = dreambear.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter


############################################################
# Facility specific properties.
# Provides extra control for each logger.
############################################################

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].handlers = 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].handlers = 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/dreambear].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/dreambear].handlers = 5dreambear.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
```

Or should I just use Log4J?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `dreambear` the name of the web application? Or the servlet?

In these 2 lines,

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/dreambear].level = INFO 
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/dreambear].handlers = 5dreambear.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
```

It needs to be **the name of the web application** in **[/dreambear]** and not that of the servlet.
Then your logging will work.

also try changing logging level to ALL here

```
5dreambear.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = ALL
```

Comment: Yes, it's the name of my web app. It has only one servlet, therefore the confusion.

Comment: @Bart van Heukelom : Okay then try asking on stackoverflow for a better response

Comment: Ok I'll try that. I already have another Tomcat related question there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942655/getting-tomcat-to-reload-a-web-app-with-a-static-context

Comment: Yes, saw that. I meant log4j stuff is better answered on SO, so you'd get a better recommendation.